# base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type

Tags: c++, pointers, g++

First, the code:

```
// ...

struct node_list {
    node_list *prev;
    node *target;     // node is defined elsewhere in the application
    node_list *next;
    };

node_list nl_head;

int main() {
    nl_head->prev = &nl_head;
    // ...
    return 0;
    }
```

I get an error:

```
make (in directory: #####)
g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -o main main.cc
main.cc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cc:38:9: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘node_list’
  nl_head->prev = &nl_head;
         ^
Makefile:8: recipe for target 'main' failed
make: *** [main] Error 1
Compilation failed.
```

As far as I can tell my syntax is correct. Can anyone point out the error?

Before anyone flags it as a duplicate, I am aware it is similar to a couple other questions but none of their solutions seem to work for me. Unless I'm doing it wrong, which I'll admit is possible, but that's why I'm here.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`nl_head` is not a pointer.  try `nl_head.prev`

Comment: I thought that it had to be '->' because 'prev' is a pointer. Although that did fix it so I was obviously wrong. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 10):

As suggested by the error message and your question title. `nl_head` is not a pointer so you cannot use the `-­>` operator.

Make it a pointer. You will also need to allocate memory before you can use it.

Alternatively, you can *not* make it a pointer but instead use the dot operator to access its member.

Answer (score 2):

`nl_head`  is an object of the `node_list` structure, it is not a pointer,  so use the dot operator and assign the loa:

```
nl_head.prev = &nl_head;
```